# Get View on VF page

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I want to get object view on a custom VF page.

eg: when we click on a object in salesforce we get a view i want that view on a VF page which i create.

Can anybody help me to solve this problem. If possible provide me the apex-code

Thanks
Anu

Answer (score 1):

That view is called a detail page. There is in fact an visualforce component called [apex:detail](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_detail.htm) that does exactly what you want.

Comment: thanks it was a great help. But i want to display all the list of records. What should i do? And also want to default value with apex:details which will make much easier to work. eg: If we have field FName, Lname, Addrss, ph no etc. I want to display only 1 field address which should contain(Fname, Lname, ph) no need to update but need in UI when clicked on a button. If possible please help me.